# Deploying Angular 6 Universal using Elastic Beanstalk AWS

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, typescript, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, angular-universal

I am working on Angular 6 Universal on AWS. My website is hosted on AWS and i deploy using Elastic Beanstalk.

My Angular 6 Universal application was created using **@ng-toolkit/universal** using angular CLI which automatically adds Required server configuration in the application.

I faced the problem while deployment.My deployment always gets failed. I have no idea how to deploy production version of compiled angular as well as Nodejs server files along with it. I google searched and i couldn't able to find a proper solution.

Steps i did :

1. *ng new my-app --routing*
2. *ng add @ng-toolkit/universal*
3. Did required changes in few files
4. Ran the command to compile the production version and generated Server files
5. **/dist** folder created with browser and server version

The folder structure look something like this :

[image: folder structure]

I tried to deploy **/dist** to server but fails. i tried to deploy whole root folder with Typescript but still fails.

I finally figured out the problem and i created this thread so that it may help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk by default tries to run **Server.js** file first if it couldn't find then **app.js** if it couldn't find then will run command **"npm start"**

So there is 2 solutions

1. The file **local.js**(created by @ng-toolkit) runs the nodejs server. so you either rename it to **server.js** or **app.js** so that EB will execute it after successful deployment and then deploy the whole root folder to your server using **"eb deploy"** command.
2. Or else copy the **local.js** to **/dist** folder and rename it to app.js/server.js and edit the file to change the directory ***"./server_filename"***

```js
// generated by @ng-toolkit/universal
    const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
    
    const server = require('./_server'); <!-- Renamed to _server -->
    
    server.app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log("Listening on: http://localhost:" + port );
    });
```

And the final and important step.

1. Elastic beanstalk fails the deployment and throws error on @ng-toolkit installation. Since @ng-toolkit/universal is on beta, it may have bug.
2. So open **package.json** file and move ***"@ng-toolkit/universal":*** from ***dependencies*** to ***devDepedencies***

That's it! Now deploy and your application should work. Please let me know if you face any problem or another best practice of this deployment.